# Running a cron job on a WP plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I've slightly modified a wp-plugin that I had in order to make it work automatically.

The address is http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wp_posts&add=add

The problem is that I can't get it to work and my cron is giving me an error when im using it.

I call it with

```
wget -O /dev/null http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wp_posts&add=add
```

and as a result I get

```
--2015-04-23 10:00:01--  http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wp_posts
Resolving www.example.com... 46.105.40.207
Connecting to www.example.com|46.105.40.207|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fwp-admin%2Fadmin.php%3Fpage%3Dwp_posts&reauth=1 [following]
--2015-04-23 10:00:03--  http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fwp-admin%2Fadmin.php%3Fpage%3Dwp_posts&reauth=1
Reusing existing connection to www.example.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: “/dev/null”

 0K ...                                                     237M=0s

 2015-04-23 10:00:03 (237 MB/s) - “/dev/null” saved [3180]
```

So it seems that since this is admin restricted, i have no way to run it.

Any idea on how I can change that ?

Comment: You need change plugin settings make this url public eg, http://www.example.com/your_cron_page?page=wp_posts&add=add, due to wp-admin it's means this operation is for admin only who are currently logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this snippet in your **functions.php** file, and you can run it via public url eg http://example.com/cron

```
function my_CronJob() {
    global $wp;
    // Check that we are getting "cron" slug from url.
    if($wp->request == 'cron'){
        // Run you cron script here.  

        die();
    }
}

add_filter('template_redirect', 'my_CronJob');
```

Or if you want to use wordpress actual standards you can check this [article](https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-cron-jobs/).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you. Since I include some API in it, should I include them outside or inside the function ?

Comment: you can make you whole cron job logic in a particular function
after that in my_CronJob if statment  you can call that function, eg if($wp->request == 'cron') { your_cron_job_logic_function(); die(); }

Comment: Working great for the function part, although, i'm not sure how I am supposed to call it with the cron?
I get:
     http://www.example.com/automatemovie
    Resolving www.example.com... MY.IP.ADD.RESS
    Connecting to www.example.com|MY.IP.ADD.RESS|:80...                          connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
    2015-04-24 13:00:03 ERROR 404: Not Found.